# Android studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie and i created my first program Hello World, but while running it shows this error message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My build.gradle is

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.helloworld"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
 dependencies {
  // App dependencies compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
  }
```

Please help me.......

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning project, And invalidate cache and restart

Comment: the error message is higher in the log. It should tell why did it fail

Comment: how to invalidate cache @Nilesh

Comment: In Android Studio go `File->Invalidate caches /restart`

Comment: and i cleaned my project, then it shows no error but when i try to run the program it again shows this error @Nilesh

Comment: @Nilesh i dont see anything like that in file

Comment: So i did Invalidate caches /restart, but still when i try to run the program the error again pops up

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by downloading the latest version of gradle.

and then goto File ----> Invalidate caches/restart

and it's work for me